# jmeter multiple users problem

Tags: php, performance, apache2, jmeter

We are using Jmeter to test our Php application running on the Apache 2 web server.  I can load up Jmeter to use 25 or 50 threads and the load on the server does not increase, however the response time from the server does.  The more threads the slower the response time.  It seems like Jmeter or Apache is queuing the requests.  I have changed the maxclients value in apache web server configuration file, but this does not change the problem.  While Jmeter is running I can use the application and get respectable response times.  What gives?  I would expect to be able to tax my server down to 0% idle by increase the number of threads.  Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Update: I found that if I remove sessions from my application I am able to simulate a full load on the server.  I have tried to re-enable sessions and use an HTTP Cookie Manager for each thread, but it does not seem to make an impact.

Comment: Update2: I have found that if I change the session id that is passed as a parameter I can load up the server.  If I use the same session ID, all of the requests are queued up and are processed sequentially.  This results in the server sitting at about 80% idle and not changing no matter how many requests that I throw at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to identify where the bottleneck is occurring, and then attempt to remediate the problem.

- The JMeter client should be running on a well equipted machine.  I prefer a Solaris/Unix server running the JVM, but for <200 threads, a modern windows machine will do just fine.  JMeter can become a bottleneck, and you won't get any meaningful results once it does.  Additionally, it should run on a separate machine to what your testing, and preferable on the same network.  The WAN latency can become a problem if your test rig and server are far apart.
- The second thing to check is your Apache workers.  Apache has a module - mod_status - which will show you the state of every worker.  It's possible to have your pool size set too low.  From the mod_status, you'll be able to see how many workers are in use.  To few, and Apache won't have any workers to process requests, and the requests will queue up.  Too many, and Apache may exhaust the memory on the box it's running on.
- Next, you should check your database.  If it's on a separate machine, the database could have an IO or CPU shortage.
- If your hitting a bottleneck, and the server and db are on the same machine, you'll generally hit a CPU, RAM, or IO limit.  I listed those in the order in which they are easiest to identify.  If you get a CPU bound app, you can easily see you CPU usage go to 100%.  If you run out of RAM, your machine will start swapping.  On both Windows and unix it's fairly easy to see your available free RAM.  Lastly, you may be IO bound.  This too can be monitored using various tools or stats, but it's not as obvious as CPU.

Lastly, specifically to your question, the one thing that stands out is it's possible to have a huge number of session files stored in a single directory.  Often PHP stores session information in files.  If this directory gets large, it will take increasingly long amount of time for PHP to find the session.  If you ran your test will cookies turned off, the PHP app may have created thousands of session files for each user request.  On a Windows server, it will slow down faster than on a unix server, do to differences in the way directories are stored on the two operating systems.

Comment: The final fix for me was to change the session ids that were being passed to the php pages.  As it turns out, Apache/PHP will process each request that has a matching session id in a serial fashion.  If your testing tool is using 10 users, you must make sure you have 10 _different_ session ids, otherwise all 10 users are treated as the same and each request will wait for the last one to finish.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a constant throughput timer?  If Jmeter can't service the throughput with the threads allocated to it, you'll see this queueing and blowouts in the response time.  To figure out if this is the problem, try adding more threads.

I also found a report of this happening when there are javascript calls inside the script.  In this instance, try to move javascript calls to the test plan element at the top of the script, or look for ways to pre-calculate the value.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking a static file served by apache and not by PHP to see if the problem is in the Apache config or the PHP config.

Also check your network connections and configuration. Our JMeter testing was progressing nicely until it hit a wall. Eventually realized we only had a 100Mb connection and it was saturated, going to gigabit fixed it. Your network cards or switch may be running at a lower speed than you think, especially if their speed setting is "auto".